# Display certain info on the contact page sidebar only

Tags: php, magento, if-statement

I am more familiar with WordPress, however I am working on a Magento installation and I want to  display certain info on the contact page sidebar only.

I am in `left.phtml` and am aware that the usual WordPress `if is_page('contacts')` doesn't work.

I was given this code, but it doesn't work:

```
<?php if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/contacts" ) { ?>
```

Does anyone have any experience in this?

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your question your code is working but talking in the magento way the below code can be used in your case.

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'contacts')
{
  echo "This is contact page.";
}
```

Comment: doesnt seem to be working - i have edited your code to change my page to 'contact' which is how it is identified in the cms-pages. thanks for helping but i cant get it working

Comment: @DanDavies: you could `var_dump(Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier())` and check what exactly identifier is being used by the contact page.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use this snippet in contacts.xml rather than hard coding the condition into the template:

```
<contacts_index_index translate="label">
...
<reference name="right">
    <block type="cms/block" name="customblockname">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cms_block_name</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
</contacts_index_index>
```

In this case I inserted a cms block to the right sidebar, but you can use you own template file. See [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/page')->getPage()->getIdentifier() == 'contacts'){
    echo "This is contact page.";
}
```